# Can't assign permission set Trend Report Data in CRM Analytics to user The user license doesnt allow the permission Trend Report Data in CRM Analytics

Tags: licenses, crm-analytics

I am trying to assign permission:

```
Trend Report Data in CRM Analytics
```

To a user via a `Permission Set`

The user has a full EE Salesforce / Sales Cloud license.

When I add the user, I get the error:

> Can't assign permission set Trend Report Data in CRM Analytics to user X. The user license doesn't allow the permission: Trend Report Data in CRM Analytics

I am added to the permission set.

But I cannot figure out what license or feature license or permission license I am meant to add.

The documentation is not very clear:

- [Trend Salesforce Reports](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_trend_create.htm&type=5)

Comment: SF Help docs have a section at the top that talks about required license. In this case: _Available with CRM Analytics, which is available for an extra cost in Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited Editions. Also available in Developer Edition_ . https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_help_setup_general.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks @identigral - Whats confusing is that we don't have any "CRM Analytics" licenses, yet I have access to this capability